# How to get big Image size in grid with Tailwind v2 like in Tailwind v3

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind v2 because Tailwind v3 breaks with iphone 6.

But how to get  big Image size in grid with Tailwind v2 https://test-responsive-site.netlify.app/tailwind/v2/ like in Tailwind v3 https://test-responsive-site.netlify.app/tailwind/v3/ :

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
      </head>
      <body>
            
      <section class="px-3 py-5 bg-neutral-100 lg:py-10">
        <div class="grid lg:grid-cols-2 items-center justify-items-center gap-5"> 
          <div class="order-2 lg:order-1 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <p class="text-4xl font-bold md:text-7xl text-orange-600">25% OFF</p>
            <p class="text-4xl font-bold md:text-7xl">SUMMER SALE</p>
            <p class="mt-2 text-sm md:text-lg">For limited time only!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="order-1 lg:order-2">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615397349754-cfa2066a298e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1887&q=80" class="w-80 h-80 object-cover lg:w-[500px] lg:h-[500px]">
          </div>  
        </div>
    </section>

      </body>
    </html>
```

code is same in tailwind v3 just cdn changes:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
            
      <section class="px-3 py-5 bg-neutral-100 lg:py-10">
        <div class="grid lg:grid-cols-2 items-center justify-items-center gap-5"> 
          <div class="order-2 lg:order-1 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <p class="text-4xl font-bold md:text-7xl text-orange-600">25% OFF</p>
            <p class="text-4xl font-bold md:text-7xl">SUMMER SALE</p>
            <p class="mt-2 text-sm md:text-lg">For limited time only!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="order-1 lg:order-2">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615397349754-cfa2066a298e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1887&q=80" class="w-80 h-80 object-cover lg:w-[500px] lg:h-[500px]">
          </div>  
        </div>
    </section>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in v3 according to the official docs they have added `grid-flow-dense` utility

> [Add grid-flow-dense utility (#8193)](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#added-5)

> This PR adds a missing utility for the gridAutoFlow plugin. `.grid-flow-dense` allows users to fill the gaps on a grid container without overwriting the current grid definition and forcing it to have only one row or column.

In summary

- In `Tailwind v3`, the grid utility classes have been updated to include responsive breakpoints for controlling the grid columns, so you can use classes like `lg:grid-cols-2` to set the number of columns for a specific breakpoint.
- In `Tailwind v2`, the grid classes do not include responsive breakpoints, so you will need to use other utility classes to achieve a similar effect.

---

Unfortunately, presently you can't achieve the functionality you desired using v2, You may have to consider switching to use `flex` instead of `grid` to get the similar  functionality.